# CLion doesn't see LLDB in Docker image

Tags: docker, clion, remote-debugging, lldb

I use CLion 2023 in Windows and use Docker toolchain. I have llvm-17 installed in my docker-build image (Ubuntu based). There are `lldb` and `lldb-server` in `/usr/bin`.

Why CLion doesn't see LLDB in my image and doesn't allow me to choose `/usr/bin/lldb'?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't use CLion, so maybe this is off.  But from the warning under the line where you specify `/usr/bin/lldb` it looks like CLion can figure out the version of the llvm tools you have installed.  So it looks like it can see it, but then it either doesn't like lldb altogether, or doesn't like that version.  The warning message is pretty vague.